# Finding response time grouped by intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, group-by

I have a table where I have certain logs and their response time. I can query the table to get the average response time over the last 1000 records by doing:

```
SELECT timestamp, count(*), avg(response_time) FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1000

-- timestamp            count(*)      avg(response_time)
-- 2020-03-17 11:58:37  1000          0.27
```

However, I would like to get this this over the past N records per thousand records (to see the progression of response times over time, in chunks of 1000 requests), that is, something like:

```
SELECT timestamp, count(*), avg(response_time) FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1000
  UNION
SELECT timestamp, count(*), avg(response_time) FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1000, 1000
  UNION ...

-- timestamp            count(*)      avg(response_time)
-- 2020-03-17 11:58:37  1000          0.27
-- 2020-03-17 11:38:09  1000          0.52
-- 2020-03-17 11:04:11  1000          1.04
-- and keep going, in groups of 1000 records...
```

Would there be a cleaner way to do this where I could group things by chunks of 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using window functions.  But, alas, you can't in MySQL 5.7.  Instead, use variables:

```
SELECT MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp), count(*), avg(response_time)
FROM (SELECT t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT t.* FROM table  ORDER BY timestamp) t
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
     ) t
GROUP BY floor( (seqnum - 1) / 1000 )
ORDER BY MIN(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT count(*) no_records, avg(response_time) avg_response_time
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 day
```

If you want this on a per-hour basis:

```
SELECT 
    date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') hr, 
    count(*) no_records, 
    avg(response_time) avg_response_time
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 day
GROUP BY date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00)
ORDER BY hr
```

Or if you want to group by chunks of 1000 records, then (assuming MySQL 8.0), you can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT 
    min(timestamp) first_timestamp,
    last(timestamp) first_timestamp,
    count(*) no_records, 
    avg(response_time) avg_response_time
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 day
GROUP BY floor((row_number() over(order by timestamp) - 1) / 1000)
ORDER BY first_timestamp
```

Comment: no, I've updated the question. This gives me only one result -- I want a result per 1000 records...

Comment: thanks for the update. But this would group per hour (I could just as well `GROUP BY hour(timestamp)` given an interval of less than 24 hours. How would I group by every 1000 records?

Comment: ha, that new answer is great! But, alas, I'm on MySQL 5.7 :/